# Is this loop possible to do using simple LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I got a class called BG which has a property called Name Code.
I instantiate an object called bgList.
Now I am trying to get all the Code of the objects which have their 'Crop' property set to cropName.

I would like to convert the following working code to linq but for the life of me am unable to do that - am quite sure that I am missing something:

```
    List<string> breedingGroupsAndRoles = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < bgList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (bgList[i].Crop == cropName)
            breedingGroupsAndRoles.Add(bgList.[i].Code);
    }
```

The closest I came was this but it only nets me the first item:

```
    breedingGroupsAndRoles.Add(bgrList.Find(c => c.Crop == cropName).Role);
```

Comment: Aside from the LINQ part, it sounds like the class should be called `BreedingGroup` rather than `BG`.

Comment: You are right Jon, that sounds better...yet more to type.
I usually rename at the end of development to get VS to rename all other instances :)

Comment: That's a really bad idea, IMO - use good names right from the start, to make development easier for the whole development cycle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
List<string> breedingGroupsAndRoles = bgList
    .Where(bg => bg.Crop == cropName)
    .Select(bg => bg.Code)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation

Comment: Wouldn't using bg.Equals(cropName) be the right way in this case?

Comment: Why? OP has also used the == Operator, i assume it is a String.

Comment: It IS a string.
Thanks a lot Tim :)

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of completeness, the [`Find` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx) you tried calling on `bgList` is not part of LINQ, it's a member of the [generic `List` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) itself.  It only returns the first element matched by the predicate you provide, which is why you were only getting one result.  You probably wanted the [FindAll method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx), which returns a list of all matching elements:

```
List<BG> breedingGroups = bgList.FindAll(c => c.Crop == cropName);
```

Note that this produces a list of matching `BG` instances rather than just their `Role` properties.  Depending on how you're processing the results this may be sufficient, otherwise you'll still need LINQ or a loop and a second list to extract the `Role` values.  In any case, an all-LINQ solution such @Tim Schmelter's is likely the better way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot bacon. Yes i tried FindAll but i couldn't chain .Role at the end.
Didn't want to do it in 2 lines :)